# Extracting coordinates/numerics between [[[ ]]] brackets

Tags: r

I have some string that I would like to clean and extract the coordinates. How can I extract all of the coordinates between the `[[[   ]]]`. I would ideally like to split the data then into two columns. i.e. `[2.026627564738345, 42.130096855579175]` into two columns. When I use the `stringr` package I cannot get the data into the correct format `str_extract_all(string, "[0-9]+")`.

```
string = "{'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPolygon', 'coordinates': [[[[2.026627564738345, 42.130096855579175], [2.027134337386292, 42.129318369819664], [2.029164142936074, 42.12929216346363], [2.03000141011964, 42.12902128891026], [2.030462444071687, 42.127362495684885], [2.203072843027971, 42.15036988425436], [2.205379538477963, 42.1478162294747], [2.207165940060184, 42.14673561785736], [2.207612915854434, 42.14613908227444], [2.207775800657799, 42.14561853804184], [2.205483829537552, 42.144372446110324], [2.205950958512289, 42.14387404739165], [2.208486381350138, 42.142930375615805], [2.210488892718984, 42.13962525952487]]]]}, 'properties': {'ID': '17036_AM'}}"
```

EDIT:

```
 myData <- structure(list(feat = c("{'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPolygon', 'coordinates': [[[[2.026627564738345, 42.130096855579175], [2.027134337386292, 42.129318369819664], [2.029164142936074, 42.12929216346363], [2.03000141011964, 42.12902128891026], [2.030462444071687, 42.127362495684885], [2.205483829537552, 42.144372446110324], [2.205950958512289, 42.14387404739165], [2.208486381350138, 42.142930375615805], [2.210488892718984, 42.13962525952487]]]]}, 'properties': {'ID': '17036_AM'}}", 
                                  "{'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[1.668808716130723, 41.28581667047598], [1.663713623483673, 41.28767316900236], [1.659490774696369, 41.29140102358528], [1.652624690326509, 41.29338150305692], [1.64955519530116, 41.293865899507274], [1.645717264137523, 41.2952985993481], [1.692803688222376, 41.31043053843222], [1.687189184529872, 41.3000802933502], [1.684360007231717, 41.28843442555105], [1.675222669574866, 41.28735746334875], [1.671613137218604, 41.28479468767177], [1.668808716130723, 41.28581667047598]]]}, 'properties': {'ID': '08251'}}"
)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Then I can run:

```
modData <- myData %>%
  transmute(
    stream_in(textConnection(gsub("'", '"', feat)))
  )
```

Comment: That looks like JSON, so use a JSON parser.

Comment: I would prefer to use a JSON parser but I also cannot get that to work...

Comment: For example. When I use the `jsonlite` package: `fromJSON(txt = string)` I get the following error: `Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                      {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': 
                     (right here) ------^`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strings are valid JSON except that it's using single instead of double quotes for the keys.  So these need to be swapped first.  Also, the two examples are a slightly different format but you can try:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)

dat <- stream_in(textConnection(gsub("'", "\"", myData$feat)))

dat %>%
  pluck("geometry", "coordinates") %>%
  set_names(dat$properties$ID) %>%
  map_df(~ `dim<-`(.x, tail(dim(.x), 2)) %>% as_tibble, .id = "id")

# A tibble: 21 x 3
   id          V1    V2
   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 17036_AM  2.03  42.1
 2 17036_AM  2.03  42.1
 3 17036_AM  2.03  42.1
 4 17036_AM  2.03  42.1
 5 17036_AM  2.03  42.1
 6 17036_AM  2.21  42.1
 7 17036_AM  2.21  42.1
 8 17036_AM  2.21  42.1
 9 17036_AM  2.21  42.1
10 08251     1.67  41.3
# ... with 11 more rows
```

Comment: The first line `stream_in` is actually better than what I was hoping for. My goal is to plot these coordinates (I have more than one observations coordinates), what would be the best approach to take with the column `geometry.coordinates`. It is nested in `c(..., ...)`. Would I have to do something specific to this column in order to plot it later on?

Comment: A way to simplify the results into a matrix is included in my answer - did you want something different?

Comment: I have added a new data set `myData`. it is the same but with 2 rows in a data frame. Each row is a geographical region which contains coordinates. I would eventually like to plot these coordinates so I am just thinking of the best way to keep them in the data frame.

Comment: Where did this data come from? Your updated example has a new error in it (a missing `]` in the first string).  Errors need to be fixed before the data can be parsed.

Comment: I have updated the data. Yes, there was a small error due to me (I am removing many coordinates otherwise the example size would be too large). I also added some code.

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_match_all` :

```
stringr::str_match_all(string, '\\[(\\d+\\.\\d+), (\\d+\\.\\d+)\\]')[[1]][, -1]

#                     [,1]                [,2]                
# [1,] "2.026627564738345" "42.130096855579175"
# [2,] "2.027134337386292" "42.129318369819664"
# [3,] "2.029164142936074" "42.12929216346363" 
# [4,] "2.03000141011964"  "42.12902128891026" 
# [5,] "2.030462444071687" "42.127362495684885"
# [6,] "2.203072843027971" "42.15036988425436" 
# [7,] "2.205379538477963" "42.1478162294747"  
# [8,] "2.207165940060184" "42.14673561785736" 
# [9,] "2.207612915854434" "42.14613908227444" 
#[10,] "2.207775800657799" "42.14561853804184" 
#[11,] "2.205483829537552" "42.144372446110324"
#[12,] "2.205950958512289" "42.14387404739165" 
#[13,] "2.208486381350138" "42.142930375615805"
#[14,] "2.210488892718984" "42.13962525952487"
```